# NumberFormatException in preparing index using Elasticsearch 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3 *(both server and java client)*

Code for preparing index:

```
private TransportClient txClient;
// client intialization

Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("name", "Dev");
values.put("id", "2f3cc5d4-9c4c-4a49-9ebd-c8cd86758118");
values.put("salary", "50000");

IndexResponse response = txClient
             .prepareIndex("novel","books", "1de90f05-7cc8-4796-9e92-5b766e8bb0d1")
             .setSource(values).execute().actionGet();
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [id]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "2f3cc5d4-9c4c-4a49-9ebd-c8cd86758118"];
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:329)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:309)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseAndMergeUpdate(DocumentParser.java:738)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDynamicValue(DocumentParser.java:625)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:442)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:262)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:122)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:580)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndexOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:559)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:212)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:224)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:158)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:639)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:271)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2f3cc5d4-9c4c-4a49-9ebd-c8cd86758118"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
>       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.longValue(AbstractXContentParser.java:145)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.LongFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(LongFieldMapper.java:275)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:241)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
>       ... 23 more

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the index

Comment: @DhruvPal I have not defined mapping anywhere. It will map it dynamically.

Comment: I cant understand why you are inserting a uid in 'id' field as since es also provides id to each document. Is there some requirement like that.Also I see Caused by: MapperParsingException so I guess its related to mapping

Comment: Can you share dynamic mapping which is present  when exception occurs

Comment: @DhruvPal I am setting Map<String,String> in `setSource()`, I am not adding fields of objects.

Comment: Yeah I can see that , Thats weird

Comment: @DhruvPal I know ES will add UID if  id is not present in the object. But I have a requirement of adding it manually for an ORM tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114731/discussion-between-dev--and-dhruv-pal).

Answer (score 1):

For the very first time if you inserted document having ID field and its value is in any of the number types then it will set Long type to the IDfield if it could not find any mapping for the ID field in mappings.

So if you want your id field as String, you should explicitly map it to string data type in mapping before inserting any of the documents into your index.